# Should the tags definition and terminology be merged

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we create a tag synonym for the [definition](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) and [terminology](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) tags?

Currently the tag wiki for
[definition](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) says *"to be used for any question where one needs to understand the meaning of a specific term, or usage of a specific word"*
[terminology](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) says *"For questions about terms used in personal finance, alternative names for concepts, etc."*

Answer (score 3):

The tagged questions all look pretty similar. I've made `terminology` the primary as it has more questions now and seems a bit more specific.

I've roughly merged the two tag wikis to get:

> For questions about the meaning and usage of specific terms used in personal finance, alternative names for concepts, etc.

Comment: +1 for merging the tags, for making 'terminology' the primary, and for your tag wiki excerpt.

Comment: Think about Google, though. Would people search for "____ definition", or "_____ terminology"? On that basis, I suggest "definition" be the primary, so it appears in the page and is indexed.

Comment: @Chris - good point re Google. Can you find any examples where we actually appear in the google results for XXX definition? I tried searching based on some random picks from current list of 'definition' questions and couldn't find anything.

Comment: "bid ask definition" ... but then again, we rank on that (quoted above the top result) without the word "definition".

Comment: @Chris I've gone with terminology for now - let's start a new meta question if you think it's worth shifting to definition.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I don't have access to analytics or anything so I can't say what the impact would be; it was a hunch is all.